# Populate combobox of datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to populate the combobox of datagridview but not getting any result 
here is my code

```
 Private Sub loadcombo()
    Dim cmb1 As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(dgventry.Columns("Party"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
    Try
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        sqlstr = "SELECT LedgerTab.lname, LedgerTab.lcode FROM LedgerTab WHERE ((LedgerTab.lgcode='LG27' OR LedgerTab.lgcode = 'LG4' OR LedgerTab.lgcode = 'LG33' OR LedgerTab.lgcode = 'LG23' OR LedgerTab.lgcode = 'LG26' ) and LedgerTab.comcode = @comcode and LedgerTab.isdeleted='N') ORDER BY LedgerTab.lname ASC"
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comcode", compcode)
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        cmb1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        cmb1.ValueMember = "lcode"
        cmb1.DisplayMember = "lname"
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub loadcombo()
    Dim cmb1 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Try
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        '   no need to open, .FILL method automatically does this for you
        'con.Open()        
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        sqlstr = "SELECT LedgerTab.lname, LedgerTab.lcode FROM LedgerTab WHERE ((LedgerTab.lgcode='LG27' OR LedgerTab.lgcode = 'LG4' OR LedgerTab.lgcode = 'LG33' OR LedgerTab.lgcode = 'LG23' OR LedgerTab.lgcode = 'LG26' ) and LedgerTab.comcode = @comcode and LedgerTab.isdeleted='N') ORDER BY LedgerTab.lname ASC"        
        adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comcode", compcode)
        adapter.Fill(ds)        
        '   no need to close, connection has already been closed by FILL
        'con.Close()

        cmb1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        cmb1.ValueMember = "lcode"
        cmb1.DisplayMember = "lname"

        '   lcode here refers to the column in dgvEntry's datasource.
        '   it must have the same data type as the lcode in LedgerTab table
        cmb1.Name = "lcode" 
        cmb1.DataPropertyName = "lcode"

        dgvEntry.Columns.Add(cmb1)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```